# Error loading excel file when trying to run row by row

Tags: pandas, python-3.8, import-from-excel

I have a code for validating data from an excel-file and I'm trying to get the code to validate row by row from the file. I use this method with importing pandas since it works fine for loading lists for email sendings successfully, so naturally I run the following similar code:

```
import pandas as pd
from validate_email import validate_email

email_list = pd.read_excel('/home/simon/Documents/Emaillist/test/test.xlsx')

emails = email_list['EMAIL']

for i in range(len(emails)):
    email = emails[i]


is_valid = validate_email(email_address='email_list', 
check_regex=True, check_mx=True, from_address='test@gmail.com', 
helo_host='smtp.gmail.com', smtp_timeout=10, 
dns_timeout=10, use_blacklist=True, debug=True)

print(is_valid)
```

For some reason I get the following error message:

`Validation for 'email_list' failed: Invalid email address.`

How can I get this to run as I want it? I've been trying different solutions like changing email_adress='emails' but I'm out ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from validate_email import validate_email

email_list = pd.read_excel('/home/simon/Documents/Emaillist/test/test.xlsx')

emails = email_list['EMAIL'].tolist()

for i in range(len(emails)):
    email = emails[i]
    is_valid = validate_email(email_address=email, check_regex=True, check_mx=True, from_address='test@gmail.com', helo_host='smtp.gmail.com', smtp_timeout=10, dns_timeout=10, use_blacklist=True, debug=False)
    print(is_valid)
```

This is more what you want.  the indentation is quite important.  Also, this is really slow.

Comment: This works fine if we were to add manually, but it still doesn't run from a list from .xlsx..